# Execute command in dynamic directories via shell script

Tags: directory-structure, replace, text

My main directory is

```
/home/hts/.hts/tvheadend/input/dvb/networks/1d38df81855dee2d39e692ecc4caf05c/muxes
```

In there are many more directories with radomly generated names

Example:

```
/027941cc4936a3a3515c78487abc5445/  
/4ab4097f4089f9e6d3c062a96f027707/  
/8224af212d24d291570864021d9107a3/  
/bffd49d7d6af0f6405b1dba81df70d89/
```

Again in those folders is one file (named "config") and one subfolder (named "services".
In the subfolder "services" there are files with a radomly generated name.

Example:

```
/home/hts/.hts/tvheadend/input/dvb/networks/1d38df81855dee2d39e692ecc4caf05c/muxes/027941cc4936a3a3515c78487abc5445/services/02f1f0807a9228c6543425c4f47312e0
```

I want a simple script that enters every single folder under "muxes" and for each of those folders enters the subfolder "services" and replaces the term

```
"enabled": true,
```

through

```
"enabled": false,
```

in every file of that folder.

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: countless versions of find in addition with executing seg command.
for example:
sudo find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/\"enabled\": true,/\"enabled\": false,/g' {} \;
which is not enough by far.

Comment: this looks good for me what is wrong with it ?

Comment: well it would change those values in the file "config" as well as in the files of the folder "services". It shouldnt change the "config" file. On top somehow its not recursive.. The command only changes the files while being executed in the same directory. As soon as you execute it in a higher directory it wont change a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as has been posted in the comments so many options;

```
#!/bin/bash

find /home/hts/.hts/tvheadend/input/dvb/networks/1d38df81855dee2d39e692ecc4caf05c/muxes -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read ad; do
  find "$ad/config/services/" -type f -exec sed -i 's/"enabled": true,/"enabled": true,/' '{}' \;
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

dirarr=($(find /home/hts/.hts/tvheadend/input/dvb/networks/1d38df81855dee2d39e692ecc4caf05c/muxes -maxdepth 1 -type d))

for dir in ${dirarr[@]}; do
  editfile=$(ls -1 $dir/config/services/)
  sed -i 's/"enabled": true,/"enabled": false,/' $editfile
done
```

Comment: I'm running the script as root. Rights are set as following:
-rwx------ 1 hts video  306 Dez  4 20:44 02f1f0807a9228c6543425c4f47312e0
First example: The script runs fine (no error message) but the values won't change.
Second example: I get the error message "sed: can't read 02f1f0807a9228c6543425c4f47312e0: No such file or directory"

Comment: debug it, use `bash -x bash-script.sh`

Comment: Changing the first example from:
find "$ad/config/services/" -type f -exec sed -i 's/"enabled": true,/"enabled": true,/' '{}' \;
to
find "$ad/services/" -type f -exec sed -i 's/"enabled": true,/"enabled": false,/' '{}' \;
..works